# Setting Connection Parameters via ADO for SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server, binding, ado

Is it possible to set a connection parameter on a connection to SQL Server and have that variable persist throughout the life of the connection? The parameter must be usable by subsequent queries.

We have some old Access reports that use a handful of VBScript functions in the SQL queries (let's call them GetStartDate and GetEndDate) that return global variables. Our application would set these before invoking the query and then the queries can return information between date ranges specified in our application.

We are looking at changing to a ReportViewer control running in local mode, but I don't see any convenient way to use these custom functions in straight T-SQL.

I have two concept solutions (not tested yet), but I would like to know if there is a better way. Below is some pseudo code.

1. Set all variables before running Recordset.OpenForward

   ```
   Connection->Execute("SET @GetStartDate = ...");  
   Connection->Execute("SET @GetEndDate = ...");
   // Repeat for all parameters
   ```

Will these variables persist to later calls of `Recordset->OpenForward`? Can anything reset the variables aside from another `SET/SELECT @variable` statement?

2. Create an ADOCommand "factory" that automatically adds parameters to each ADOCommand object I will use to execute SQL

   ```
   // Command has been previously been created
   ADOParameter *Parameter1 = Command->CreateParameter("GetStartDate");
   ADOParameter *Parameter2 = Command->CreateParameter("GetEndDate");
   // Set values and attach etc...
   ```

What I would like to know if there is something like:

```
Connection->SetParameter("GetStartDate", "20090101");
Connection->SetParameter("GetEndDate", 20100101");
```

And these will persist for the lifetime of the connection, and the SQL can do something like @GetStartDate to access them. This may be exactly solution #1, if the variables persist throughout the lifetime of the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has ventured an answer I'm guessing there isn't an elegant solution, that said:

Global cursors persist for the duration of the connection and can be accessed from any SQL or stored proc so you could execute this once on the connection:

```
DECLARE KludgeKursor CURSOR GLOBAL STATIC FOR
SELECT StartDate = '2010-01-01', EndDate = '2010-04-30'
OPEN KludgeKursor
```

and in your stored procedures:

```
--get the values
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
FETCH FIRST FROM GLOBAL KludgeKursor
INTO @StartDate, @EndDate

--go crazy
SELECT @StartDate, @EndDate
```

Each connection would only see their own values, so the same stored procs can be used for different connection/values. The global cursor is automatically deallocated when the connection ends

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Is it possible to change the values of StartDate and EndDate later in the connection? I'm not that great with cursors, but I'm guessing "STATIC" means immutable once it is created.

Comment: You can change the value of the local variable but not values the cursor holds, even without the static keyword, I believe. It's a good thing not being great with cursors. Actually, the CURSOR was one of the evils that came out of Pandora's box.

Comment: "not values the cursor holds, even without the static keyword" - sigh. I'll keep looking then. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @taspeotis You can, but you need to explicitly close and deallocate the cursor then declare it again with the new values